# Ng-repeat inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<ul ng-repeat="cate in restaurant.categories"><li>{{cate}}</li>
    <li ng-repeat="menuItem in restaurant.menuItems" ng-show="menuItem.category == cate">{{menuItem.name}}</li></ul>
```

I want one ng-repeat loop inside another and to show the menu only if the menuItem is in the category. I only have items in the first category loop, and empty for all the other categories.

Categories and menuItem are 2 different arrays. If the menuItem's category is under the current category it should be added to the page.

```
menuItems = {{name: dish1, category:soup},
             {name: dish2, category:beef}}
categories = {beef, soup}
```

Comment: You'll need to show an example of the `categories` and `menuItems` data and / or ideally, a Plunker example

Comment: You need to use filter in inner ng-repeat to filter second array. Just share your whole array here and i will help you to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@show-me-the-code : Bill Bi has two different array. So the best option to achieve this is by filter in inside loop as stated in my comment.

Here is the final code with filter for inside loop. I am including fiddler for quick reference.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="cate in categories">
        <li>{{cate}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems | filter:{category: cate}">{{menuItem.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

function testCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.menuItems = [{name: 'dish1', category:'soup'},
             {name: 'dish2', category:'beef'}];
    $scope.categories = ['beef', 'soup']
}
```

Fiddle : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjss1xo5/)

Comment: I'd make the filter comparison strict in order to avoid matches where the `menuItem.category` *contains* `cate`, eg `| filter:{category: cate}:true`

Comment: @Bill Bi: Please mark this answer as a answered if this is helpful to help understand other stack member.

Answer (score 0):

I would change my data representation to match what you are actually trying to display like so:

```
$scope.restaurant = {
    categories: [{
        name: "beef",
        menuItems: [{
            name: "dish1",
            "price": "$10"
        }, {
            name: "dish2",
            "price": "$15"
        }]
    }, {
        name: "soup",
        menuItems: [{
            name: "dish1",
            "price": "$20"
        }, {
            name: "dish2",
            "price": "$25"
        }]
    }]
};
```

This way you could easily match your two nested loops like this:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="cate in restaurant.categories">
        <li>{{cate.name}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="menuItem in cate.menuItems">{{menuItem.name}} - {{menuItem.price}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzwL57so/) if you would like to see it in action. 
If you need to stick to your JSON data, you will have to do filtering to pull the contents you want to display.

Comment: This is a good choice but I am not allowed to change the database