# Want to use subarray in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

My two dimensional is like this

```
  {
    "MKey1": {
      "v1": "2015-10-29 14:03:41",
      "v2": "2016-01-04 15:36:13",
      "v3": "2015-11-02 19:53:11",
      "v4": "2015-12-09 19:15:04",
      "v5": "2015-08-18 19:12:37",
      "v6": "2015-09-20 17 :00:58"
    },
    "Mkey2": {
      "v1": "2015-10-29 14:03:41",
      ".v2": "2016-01-04 15:36:13",
      "v3": "2015-11-02 19:53:11",
      "v4": "2015-12-09 19:15:04",
      "v5": "2015-08-18 19:12:37",
      "v6": "2015-09-20 17:00:58"
    }
  }
```

here almost everything is dynamic, even Key & values. Want to take first set of array and need to print inner array key values in table

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32961053/ng-repeat-inside-ng-repeat/32962050#32962050

Comment: FYI   you don't have any arrays...you have nested objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj" ng-if="$first">
  <div ng-repeat="(subkey, subvalue) in value">
    {{subvalue}}
  </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/7L706pbr/10/)**</kbd>

Comment: I've edited you with meaningful names and added the use of `value` from first `ngRepeat` where you were using `key` in object

Comment: Yes, you are almost correct. I want to print the key of first set only. I have used below code <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in resultset">
  <div ng-repeat="(subkey, subvalue) in value">
    {{subkey}} 
 </div>
</div> but dont want to print second set of array

Comment: Wow, Working well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div ng-repeat="value in object">
  <!-- get all nested objects -->
  <div ng-repeat="values in value">
    <!--get values of all nested object -->
    {{values}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use $index in parent loop

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj" ng-if="$index==0">
      {{key}} 
      <div ng-repeat="(subkey, subvalue) in value">
        {{subkey}} : {{subvalue}}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Frangly/jpe1vyrb/2/